# Using ko.viewmodel plugin to update the model

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Seems that can't call "ko.viewmodel" knockout related stuff from the jquery side

**Error :**

```
TypeError: ko.viewmodel is undefined  

viewModel = ko.viewmodel.updateFromModel(result);
```

**What I'm using:**

Using this for mapping, it results in a cleaner code:

```
coderenaissance.github.io/knockout.viewmodel/
```

At first All the code were in the Jquery side, I mean inside this function  when I was using the Mapping plugin:

```
//var vmProcess = $(function () {
//});";
```

*I removed the whole code from it cause from the very first line using ko.viewmodel was getting the undefined error*

When I switched to ko.viewmodel I found that I move everything outside the famous $, but there I can't update my model the regular way,
 don't know do you have a solution for this?
thanks in advance...

The Code:

```
var viewModel = ko.viewmodel.fromModel(serverViewModel);

//function updateModel(result) {
//    console.log('updating model');
//    viewModel = ko.viewmodel.updateFromModel(result);
//}

viewModel.addGroup = function(newgroupName) {
    console.log("Adding Group... ");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/AddGroup?groupName=" + newgroupName,
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: "POST",
        success: function(result) {
            //updateModel(result);
            ko.viewmodel.updateFromModel(viewModel,result);
        }
    });
}

//var vmProcess = $(function () {
//});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**Edit :** *Added full code*

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.viewmodel.2.0.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var serverViewModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

    var viewModel = ko.viewmodel.fromModel(serverViewModel);
    var self = this;
    viewModel.NewGroupName = '';

    viewModel.addGroup = function(newgroupName) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Admin/AddGroup?groupName=" + newgroupName,
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: "POST",
            success: function(result) {
                ko.viewmodel.updateFromModel(viewModel,result);
            }
        });
    }

    //var vmProcess = $(function () {
    //});

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("pnlSetTournament"));

</script>
```

Comment: Either `ko.viewmodel` is defined, or it isn't. It's just as global as `ko` and `$` themselves, after all. So... Is it defined?

Comment: ko.viewmodel is defined in the plugin, and it should be used in this pattern as the documentation  : ko.viewmodel.updateFromModel(viewmodel, updatedModel); like what I did, not sure I get what you mean or not, but in the $'s inner scope seems that I can't use this plugin.

Comment: Make sure you are loading the scripts in the correct order, are their any javascript errors in the console ?  Is your code above executed inside the ready function callback, or directly when loaded ? If you are using a loader ( like requireJS ) then it looks like this plugin will need some addition configuration as it expects a global 'ko' variable

Comment: The code is exactly what I am using without the scripts tags and encoding my model to json, I'm not a geek in neither of technologies(ko, Jquery), JQuery is working here, so the order shouldn't be the case, the plugin also is working by itself, unfortunately I can't use any function of it inside the $.ajax, don't know why, and that should be because of my lack of knowledge or maybe it isn't supported by the plugin, if anyone knows the solution, or found that what I did wrong, please guide me, you can test it for yourself in the jsfiddle with a sample model, my code is the same, thanks

Comment: the code above isn't in the ready section, regarding my limited knowledge, the function with $ should be executed after the document is ready, "//var vmProcess = $(function () {
//});"  and as I said earlier I tried this also, but the plugin wouldn't run inside the $ scope and I get "ko.viewmodel is undefined" . About the order also I can say JQuery>Knockout>Knockout.viewModel

Comment: You must post the exact order of all your `<script>` tags or we won't able to help.

Comment: Looks all-right on first glance. If there are no 404s (i.e. all scripts are loaded successfully) then `ko.viewmodel` will available inside the `$()` function and outside of it. Add `console.log((typeof ko), (typeof ko.viewmodel), (typeof $));` as the first line in your script. What does it say con the console?